# Similar function peek( ); (from C++) in Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, peek

Is there any similar peek(); (From C++) function in ruby? Any alternative to do this?

I've found a way to do this.

Use the StringScanner:

```
require 'strscan'
scanner = StringScanner.new(YourStringHere)
puts scanner.peek(1)
```

You can use the StringScanner to scan files as well:

```
file = File.open('hello.txt', 'rb')
scanner = StringScanner.new(file.read)
```

Comment: For those unfamiliar with C++, `peek` returns the next character without consuming input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `ungetc`. Try to look [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-ungetc).

It is not equal but you can obtain the same result.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. (And remember to accept the answer if it fits your needs :P)

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) let's you peek at the next value of an Enumerator. [IO#bytes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_byte) [IO#chars](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_char) will give you an Enumerator on a byte stream or character stream respectively.  Since you opened with "rb", I'll assume you want bytes.

```
file = File.open('hello.txt', 'rb') # assume contains text "hello\n"
fstream = file.bytes

fstream.next # => "h"
fstream.peek # => "e"
fstream.next # => "e"
...
```

Of course now you're kinda stuck with byte at a time processing on the stream.